# To open (by) a given distance

Tags: prepositions, measure-phrases

I am writing maintenance instructions together with a colleague. We are non-native and are quibbling about this sentence:

Open the door **by** 10 cm.

My colleague claims that the preposition **by** is not necessary. I claim the opposite. Neither can find a source to support his viewpoint.

Does anyone have a - supported - answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'By' is certainly not necessary here, and is arguably quite unidiomatic. I'm not going to spend a long time chasing this up in a reference work, but [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=opened+the+door+ten%2Copened+the+door+by+ten%2Copened+the+door+three%2Copened+the+door+by+three&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Copened%20the%20door%20ten%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Copened%20the%20door%20three%3B%2Cc0) strongly suggest that the inclusion of 'by' before a measure phrase here is unidiomatic (you seem to need to click on 'search' there for the full picture). An Ngram for 'opened the door by' is not useful, throwing up (almost?) entirely agency clauses (by kicking it with his foot ...).

You can do a rough check by doing a quick Google search for "opened the door by ten", "opened the door ten", and other similar phrases with reasonable numerals.

Comment: Yup. You open a door **by** turning a handle and pushing.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition "by" could be used with a measure of time, but since you are talking about distance (10 cm), the preposition would not be needed.

If the door is to be opened exactly 10 cm, the sentence would be okay as "Open the door 10 cm."  If the measurement does not need to be exact, you could say, "Open the door **at least** 10 cm" or "Open the door **no more than** 10 cm."